# Should I Rebuild SQL Server App for 64bit?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, x86, 64-bit, sql-server-2016

I am using Visual Studio 2008 write an 32bit application that will connect to SQL Server and access database. Now I see the latest SQL Server 2016 only has 64bit version. I am considering of rebuild my app for 64bit support. And just wonder whether that is necessary? What are the advantages and disadvantages of building a 64bit app, since the 32bit app can still work with the current SQL Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do so. As you noted, 32 bits programs can still connect to 64 bits servers, and 64 bits Windows can still run 32 bits software, at least in the WoW emulation mode.

Most advantages of migrating to x64 are the greater memory address space available (if your program uses a lot of virtual memory) and improved performance for CPU-intensive applications. There are a few security improvements too. Other than that, users won't see any appreciable difference.

To give you a concrete example of that, even the latest version of Visual Studio is still a 32 bits program. That gives you a clue that there isn't a great urgence in a migration, although it's nice to provide one.

Answer (score 1):

In short: No. Your application doesn't have to be 64 bit to interface with 64 bit SQL Server. 
Whilst SQL Server itself is 64 bit, there are still 32 bit drivers for it so that's all you need to worry about.

As Alejandro mentioned, 64 bit apps do have advantages, but if you're targeting the .NET platform, you can specify the AnyCPU target which will build an app that'll happily run in both modes (although be aware of pitfalls with it comes to native integer length etc)